# What does the following syntax do?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$temp =~ s/,//g
```

What is this syntax? I couldn't find it anywhere in the book "Learning Perl".  Can someone tell me what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble understanding? That's such a basic Perl statement, I can't believe your book doesn't explain it.

Comment: Take it easy, guys. It's a simple question, but it's one that's not easily googleable.

Comment: I'm sorry I offended your delicate sensibilities.  I started perl a week ago and it's been rough but I'm starting to like it.  I looked at all the regex section in the book and it wasn't there.

Comment: This is a good place to start:
http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/basic.html

Comment: When in doubt, check `perldoc perlop` to see what an operator does.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be answered merely by consulting the standard Perl documentation included with every Perl installation.

Comment: @tchrist Oh, if you put the bar that low, any question can be answered that way, given enough practice and time. :P Heck, that's how I learned Perl in the first place.

Comment: @TLP You’re welcome: that’s why we spend so much time writing it. If people think they can just come here to have us read the Perl manpages to them, there will be no end of that. Don’t give them fish, give them fish-wrappers. :)

Comment: @tchrist Oh, you're the one who wrote it? :) Thank you. Well, I did point him towards perldoc perlop.

Comment: @Jean, that is a terrible place to start, that tutorial is from Perl 4!!! Please see the [Perl Tutorial Hub](http://perl-tutorial.org/) when considering the value of a tutorial.

Comment: I used Perl for over a decade before I even knew about the `perldoc` command. And, until recently, I didn't know exactly where file tests were documented in Perldoc (it's under the `-X` functions). Perl documentation isn't always the clearest ant it isn't always easy to find what you're looking for. Look at [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html). Why don't they give an example: (Array looks like this, you say this, this is the results). You need to be patient, and point to tutorials and docs. When we are nice, we help advocate for Perl.

Comment: If you go to the real front page of that Perl tutorial, you'll see that the author has added this: "This tutorial was written in the early 1990s for version 4 of Perl. Although it is now significantly out of date, it was a popular source of information for many people over many years. It has therefore been left on-line as part of the historical archive of the Internet." The page then redirects you to http://perl-tutorial.org/. Please don't recommend that old tutorial.

Comment: 'I couldn't find it anywhere in the book "Learning Perl"' You should look harder. The substitution operator (`s///`) is introduced on page 155 and the binding operator (`=~`) is mentioned on page 157 (this is in the sixth edition, but these topics have been covered in every edition).

Comment: @user2521358 Please give a read through http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html, it's a quick read as the URL promises and covers the (very) basics of Perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

It removes all commas from `$temp`.

Comment: Information on Perl's Regular Expression matching and search/replace functionality http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html

Answer (score 4):

It removes all commas from the value in `$temp`. It returns the number of commas replaced.

---

`=~` instructs the match operator (`m//`), the substitution operator (`s///`) and the transliteration operator (`tr///`) on which variable to act.

---

`s///` is a substitution operator. Like other operators, it is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

It replaces all patterns matched by the regular expression provided between the first two delimiters (`,`) with the string defined by the literal between the last two delimiters (an empty string).

The `g` modifiers causes the operation to replace all matches instead of just the first.

Regular expressions are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 2):

This will basically remove every comma character from your variable `$temp`

Answer (score -2):

Quoting [this](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Perl-CGI-1045/2008/9/perl-Regular-Expression-usage.htm):

> =~ is a perl operator that means 'run this variable against this regular expression.

So, this regexp will remove all comma characters fro variable `$temp`.

Comment: That quote is wrong. `=~` has nothing to do with regular expressions. It instructs the match operator (m//), the substitution operator (s///) and the transliteration operator (tr///) on which variable to act.